# Automating password into sudo

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo

I'm completely new to the Linux world, but I've been able to complete a few tasks on my own.

Now, I have a task to complete that's driving me crazy.

I need to be able to send the password to `sudo`, since I can't prompt the user for the password.

What I've been able to find is

```
echo myPassword | sudo -s
```

Apparently `-s` allows `sudo` to receive the password through command input, and not user input.

I can't render my user so `sudo` won't ask me for password, since I don't know who will use this script, the script has access to their password and account names, the only thing I need it to be able to automate `sudo`.

PS: English is not my native language, sorry if I made any mistakes.

Comment: First, it is `-S` Uppercase, not `-s` lowercase (which change the shell).
Second, why can't you prompt your users for a password?
Third: What do you mean by "I can't render my user so sudo ...."??.

Comment: sorry, i dont how to express my self, i cant change the sudoers file so the system wont ask for a password, and i cant prompt my users for a password because this part of the  script is supposed to be hidden.

Comment: Under the conditions you state, there is no solution I can give.

Comment: damn, thanks :), do you know why "echo myPassword | sudo -S" wont work?