# ansible hangs in "sudo yum install"' step

Tags: linux, ansible, yum

I am trying to setup ansible (2.0) for installing software on a linux box
[image]

`ies-iesd-jktools`  is the machine with ansible.  `ies-iesd-git-06` is the target. User account is `iesdgrid` that can do sudo on target machine.

Following command hangs on remote:-

```
    ies-iesd-jktools:~/ansible$ ansible ies-iesd-git-06  \
           -i inventory  -m raw \
           -a "sudo yum install -y python-simplejson"   -vvvv

Using /usr/src/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

SUDO password: <I type password here>

Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<ies-iesd-git-06> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: None on PORT 22 TO ies-iesd-git-06
<ies-iesd-git-06> EXEC sudo yum install -y python-simplejson
```

This starts a sudo on target machine, but does not proceed as if it is waiting for password

```
$ hostname
ies-iesd-git-06
$
$ ps -ef| grep su
root       583   582  0 09:01 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo yum install -y python-simplejson
iesdgrid   811   771  0 09:05 pts/2    00:00:00 grep su
```

What is the mistake?

After a while I got

```
sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error
```

(manually login to the target machine and sudo there works. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `--become` `--become-user root` `--ask-become-pass` parameters so ansible will sudo su to root prior to executing the command.

```
ansible -m raw -a "yum install python-simplejson" testserver --ask-become-pass --become-user root --become
SUDO password:
testserver | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>

Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Static_ol6_UEK2_latest                                   | 2.3 kB     00:00
Static_ol6_latest                                        | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package python-simplejson-2.0.9-3.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo`, by design, requires an interactive shell so a password can be entered.

The cleanest way of fully automating calls to sudo is giving the user `NOPASSWD` access to all or only the necessary commands, although this potentially poses a security risk.

Detailed information about the `/etc/sudoers` configuration file can be found at http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html.

There are several threads on stackexchange dealing with the problem of automated elevated execution on linux:

- **[Specify sudo password for Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870083/specify-sudo-password-for-ansible)**
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69172/how-to-securely-automate-running-commands-as-root-with-sudo-su
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144997/sudo-su-automated-login
- https://superuser.com/questions/243499/automating-the-sudo-su-user-command
- [Automating password into sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463277/automating-password-into-sudo)

Comment: Thanks.  I am using ansible in an interactive fashion. ansible asks for "sudo" password, I type it in.  (edited question for this detail)